# Getting property from a hasOne relationship of a collection Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I have 3 models : Group, User, and Profile

Group relates to User with many to many relationship,
User relates to Profile with one to one relationship,
and User also has many to many relationship with Role model

the question is how to get the `faculty` property of profiles from user in a group whose role are "mentee" ?

i tried this, but it doesn't worked:

```
    $faculties = collect($this->mentee()->profile->faculty;
```

this is the `Group.php` and the `mentee()` method

```
class Group extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    public function mentee()
    {
        return $this->users()->whereHas(
                    'roles', function($q){
                        $q->where('name', 'mentee');
                    })
                ->get();
    }
```

here's the `User.php`

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

protected $fillable = [
    'username', 'email', 'password',
];


public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
}

public function owns($related)
{
    return $this->id == $related->user_id;
}

public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
}

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}

public function hasRole($role)
{
    if (is_string($role)) {
        return $this->roles->contains('name', $role);
    }

    return !! $this->intersect($this->roles)->count();
}

}
```

lastly, here's the `Profile.php`

```
class Profile extends Model
{

protected $fillable = [
    'user_id', 'name', 'nim', 'faculty', 'major', 'batch','religion', 'gender', 'phone', 'line_id',
];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
}
```

please let me know if i should give more details

Comment: Please add example of models that you have